# How to determine if all cell array elements are nonzero or true? Or: What is the cell array equivalent for "all"?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I'm looking for a fast way to evaluate whether any element of a cell array contains the logical value `false`. For matrix arrays there is the convenient function `all` which is not working for cells. 
I have a hard time to implement the same function for cell arrays without using loops, this solution would work, but shouldn't be an option. Any hints?

My cell array looks like that:

```
values = {  vector of values  ;  value  ; ...  ;  false  ;  ... ; value }
```

so basicallly I write the results of the process in a cell array, if there is an error in the process it returns a logic `false`. In the following I need to implement an error handling in case there was any error writing `false`

I'd really appreciate something simple like:

```
if ~all(values), do something to handle error; return; end
```

but for cell arrays...

Edit: if a cell element is a double with the value `0` it is a valid case and it shouldn't return `false`
.

Comment: What should happen for elements like `[true, false, true]` or `[false, true, true]` etc...

Comment: thats never the case. Every element is either `false` or a double(-vector) - but as said in the edit `0` is valid too!

Comment: This doesn't sound like the best way to store your data... Can't you just use a normal double array and replace all your `false`s with `NaN`?

Comment: and check of for empty elements? sounds reasonable. The reason why I store it like that, is because `values` is actually the `varargout` of a function which needs to be a cell array, and also every element has a different length, so I'd say cells are the best solution to pass the results through my functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if it is `logical` and then check if it is `false`

```
cellfun(@(x) islogical(x) && ~x, values)
```

This is true where you have a `false` so you will need

```
    if any(cellfun(@(x) islogical(x) && ~x, values))
         %do something to handle error; 
         return; 
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Would `cellfun` work?

e.g.

```
booltest = all((cellfun(@(x) all(x), values))
```

Comment: it always returns zero/false. Even when all elements of `values` are non-zero vectors of doubles (which is a non-error case). But it also needs to be robust for the case, when one cell element is a double `0`, which is valid.